# Spring read values for @Bean class from properties file

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to create Spring beans using only annotations. I am not able to load values for my @Bean class from properties file.

Here is my code:

This is my main class

```
public class AnnotationDI {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ConfigurationProvider.class);
    
    ApplicationProperties properties = (ApplicationProperties)context.getBean(ApplicationProperties.class);
    
    System.out.println(properties);
    
}}
```

Configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationProvider {

private ApplicationProperties m_applicationProperties;

@Bean
public ApplicationProperties getApplicationProperties() {
    return new ApplicationProperties();
}
}
```

Bean class

```
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class ApplicationProperties {

@Value("${longThreadCount}")
private String m_longProcessThread;

@Value("${routeTimeout}")
private String m_routeTimeout;

@Value("${updateDirectoryPath}")
private String m_updateDirectoryPath;

public String getLongProcessThread() {
    return m_longProcessThread;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ApplicationProperties [m_longProcessThread=" +m_longProcessThread"]";
}
}
```

when i run this program, I get following output

> m_longProcessThread=${longThreadCount}

Any idea what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You need to add a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` as a `public static` `@Bean` to have `@Value` resolved correctly.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Can you please mention this as answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to have `@Value` with placeholders resolved you need to register a [`PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html). As this is a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` it needs to be registered as a `static` bean so that it can be detected early on in the process.

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer() {
     return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`@PropertySource` annotation has to be used in conjunction with `@Configuration` annotation like so,

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class ApplicationProperties {
    ...
}
```

Adding `@Configuration` annotation would solve the issue in this case.